# Sorting a table in R using only a part of a string in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting

Data:

```
chr10:10003219_A_G  LoF  
chr14:983281_T_C    Missense
chr1:1283721_A_G    Splice
chr21:198727614_T_C Missense
chrX:123212_T_CA    LOF
chr1:12309123_GG_C  Missense
```

Desired output:

```
chr1:1283721_A_G    Splice 
chr1:12309123_GG_C  Missense   
chr10:10003219_A_G  LoF  
chr14:983281_T_C    Missense
chr21:198727614_T_C Missense
chrX:123212_T_CA    LOF
```

I have tried: `df[order(df$V1),]`

But this puts chr10 before any of the others.

I would like them from chr1,chr2....chX and then by position which comes after the colon in ascending order.
I have to keep the table in the same format for downstream analysis so can't string split into different columns.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `df[gtools::mixedorder(df$V1), ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_order` with `numeric = TRUE`:

```r
library(stringr)
df[str_order(df$V1, numeric = TRUE), ]
```

```r
                   V1       V2
3    chr1:1283721_A_G   Splice
6  chr1:12309123_GG_C Missense
1  chr10:10003219_A_G      LoF
2    chr14:983281_T_C Missense
4 chr21:198727614_T_C Missense
5    chrX:123212_T_CA      LOF
```